# Trouble calculating nth percentile with reductio

Tags: crossfilter, reductio

I've got some crossfilter data with dates (`d`) and values (`v`):

```
[
 {d: "2013-07-26T00:00:00.000Z", v: 2.5}
 {d: "2013-07-25T00:00:00.000Z", v: 2.64}
 // ...and many more
[
```

I've created a group for the months in Crossfilter (`crossfilter2@1.4.5`):

```
months = cf.dimension((d) => {
    const dateObj = new Date(d.d);
    // use 1-12 instead of 0-11
    return dateObj.getMonth() + 1;
});

monthsGroup = months.group();
```

So `monthsGroup.all()` returns an array of 12 objects, aggregated by month. I want those objects to include the min, max, and median, as well as the 25th and 75th percentile. Reductio (`reductio@0.6.3`) helps with the min, max, and median out of the box, so I've added a custom aggregator to add the  75th and 25th percentiles.

The following code *works*, but it's very slow:

```
const monthReducer = reductio()
.valueList(d => d.v)
.min(true)
.max(true)
.median(true)
.count(true)
.custom({
    add(p) {
        const valueList = p.valueList;
        p.p75 = getPercentile(valueList, 75);
        p.p25 = getPercentile(valueList, 25);
        return p;
    },
    remove(p) {
        const valueList = p.valueList;
        p.p75 = getPercentile(valueList, 75);
        p.p25 = getPercentile(valueList, 25);
        return p;
    },
    initial(p) {
        p.p75 = undefined;
        p.p25 = undefined;
        return p;
    },
});
```

If I remove the `.custom` block, it's much faster. This runs the code for each item in the `data`, which is unnecessary because it only needs to look at the final `valueList`. Reductio has a barely-documented `.post()` hook that I think would do the trick here, but I can't get it working.

**UPDATE:** I got the post-processing hook callback to run, but it doesn't work the way I expected.

I tried registering a new post processor with an undocumented method I saw in the source:

```
// register post-processing function to add percentiles
reductio.registerPostProcessor('addPercentiles', (prior) => {
    const all = prior();
    return () => {
        const updated = all.map((e) => {
            const valueList = e.value.valueList;
            e.value.p75 = getPercentile(valueList, 75);
            e.value.p25 = getPercentile(valueList, 25);
            return e;
        });
        return updated;
    };
});
```

and adding it to the `post()` hook:

```
// run post-processing to add the 25th & 75th %iles
this.monthsGroup.post().addPercentiles()();
```

This appears to do what I want, but only once. It doesn't re-run the post hooks when a filter is applied to another dimension.

If median is just the 50th percentile, it should be trivial to also get the 25th and 75th. I feel like I'm close, but I'm obviously doing something wrong. How can I add these aggregations to the reductio reducer?

Comment: I figured out the post-processor function must return a function. I updated my question, but now I've got a different problem; the hook doesn't happen when I thought it would.

Comment: I think the hook should run when you call `group.top` or `group.all`. If you are relying on the groups to update automatically with new values, I don't think that will work with the post-processing hooks. Can you confirm?

Comment: I don't think I'm using the hook correctly. If I add a `console.log` for instance in the `getPercentile` function, it only gets printed out when the reducer is initially applied to the group. If I filter other dimensions and do `monthsGroup.all()`, `monthsGroup.top(5)`, etc., the percentiles aren't being recalculated.
edit: As long as I have the correct `valueList`, I can manually add the percentiles after the fact, but I'd rather not, especially if the median works fine.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to just add the quantiles manually, right before rendering the chart. I have a `formatData` function does date/time formatting, and restructures the data to be more d3-friendly. Since `valueList` is still available in every element of the array, I just added a couple of lines to calculate the 25th and 27th percentiles in there.

Not ideal, but very easy!